# Confused by change of basis problem in Strang (relearning)

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

[image]

I'm trying to relearn some linear algebra, and I actually just don't understand what $M$ is referring to in this problem. Is $M$ supposed to be the change-of-basis matrix from basis $V$ to $W$? Because I think it isn't. Here is my attempt at explanation:

If by the problem, $M=V^{-1}W=V^{-1}IW$, then $M$ should be a mapping from the W basis to standard basis and from the standard basis to the V basis (making a change of basis from W to V).

When it says your answer represents $T(v)=v$ with input basis $V$ and output $W$. How does $M$ represent this identity transformation/change of base matrix? To me, $T_{V}^W=M^{-1}=W^{-1}V=W^{-1}IV$ is the identity transformation.

Or following the text, it says the columns of the transformation matrix are the coordinate representation in the new basis of the image of the transformed bases elements. Ok, $T(v_j)=Tv_j=v_j=c_{1j}w_1+c_{2j}w_2+...c_{nj}w_n$. To solve this matrix equation across all $j$, we get $W^{-1}V=T$.

I'm thoroughly confused apparently! What does $M$ represent?

The text provides the following notation:

[image]

Comment: Doesn't T map from space with base V to space with base W, going from V to standard basis to W? Your $T^W_V$ looks strange?

Comment: I guess maybe I don't have a grasp on this, but I thought $V$ whose columns are the basis $v_1,..,v_n$, is the change of basis matrix from $V$ to standard basis.

Comment: ... which is exactly why I think your representation of T looks like its inverse. You would apply V first, then W. Oh  wait, now it looks right? Maybe it is too late...

Comment: I'm so sorry for not understanding. For $T=W^{-1}V$, don't you multiply first by $V$? I think I'm missing something key here.

Comment: I think I am too tired, disregard my comment. M looks like the inverse of the matrix representation of T to me.

Comment: Thanks Emil for your help (totally get it) - it seems a weird question then maybe?

Comment: However, your equation for T looks weird, are you not saying that T is the identity transform when you write $T(v_j)=v_j$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117188/discussion-between-winston-and-emil).